# How to Debug Nemo (Linux Mint File Manager)

Tags: copy, desktop, linux-mint, file-manager

I googled how to debug nemo, someone said that can debug nemo by installing `nemo-dbg`, then type `sudo killall nemo` and `gdb nemo` on the command line.
But I still don't know how to do ...
can someone give me any information about it?

I want to debug nemo because when I copy directory on Desktop, the source and dest dir overlapped. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed `nemo-dbg`, when I killall nemo, then `nemo autorestart`, so I can't debug it.
Later I executed `nemo-launcher`, and Ctrl-C to terminate, then nemo is terminated too. 
After that I debug with `gdb nemo`, then set breakpoint, eg `b copy_move_directory`, it works.